# Make Android List Items clickable with each item pointing to a different link

Tags: android

I am getting a JSON data which contains for example the news headline and the url address for the news in the actual website.

I am using ListView to display the headlines. But how do I make it in such a way that when each item is clicked it will open up the corresponding link in the Android browser. Below is my code snippet:

```
     String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
     String link = c.getString(TAG_ALTERNATE);
    list.add(title);
                   
     final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
     listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link));
    startActivity(browserIntent);   
  }
});
```

The issue is when I click on the item it loads up the page from only 1 link. All items when clicked go to the same page.

Any idea where I have gone wrong? How do I make it in such a way that each item when clicked will go to it's respective link?

Comment: May be  Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(adapter.getItem(arg2).toString());
    startActivity(browserIntent); or Something like this.

Comment: have a switch for arg2 which is position in listview.. based on that you can have unique clicks for items

Comment: @PANDA right answer put it in answer !

Comment: please put your custom adapter class code!

Comment: You need to pass arg2 instead of link in Uri.parse(link). arg2 contains the value of the position of the item in the listview.

Comment: @LOG_TAG I'm not chasing for reputation but however followed your advice.

Answer (score 2):

put corresponding link in a list at the time of parsing json.

```
List<String> listLink= new ArrayList<String>


listLink.add(link);
```

set crosponding link of title when creation Intent in `OnItemClickListner` of `ListView`. i.e.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(listLink.get(arg2)));
    startActivity(browserIntent);   
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you should make the title and link into a javabean，so when you click a item ,you can use the javabean and get the link,at last ,you will linked to different websites.

Answer (score 1):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),s[arg2], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if(s[arg2].equals("Facebook"))
                    {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com")));
                    }
                    else if(s[arg2].equals("Twitter"))
                    {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.twitter.com")));
                    }


                    else
                    {
                                             //Message here
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

May be

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 

Uri.parse(adapter.getItem(arg2).toString()); 
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

or Something like this.

However, for understanding :

You get a 1 link because in 2 cases you getting a 1 value. It's simple. Enjoy!:)

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it. I declared another list and get the link from that list. Below is the code:

```
 list.add(title);
 linklist.add(link);

 final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);

 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(linklist.get(arg2).toString()));
startActivity(browserIntent);       
}
});
```